# How to make each category in my "image" behave like a button in android?

Tags: android

I wanted to ask that i have made an image (in Photoshop) which has a list of categories.
Now i want to make these categories clickable individually i.e when i click on 1 of the category **"in my image"**, certain thing will happen. But the problem is i can't understand **how to make categories clickable individually in an image**..?

It is a single image in which i have made 4 categories let's say A,B,C and D.
Now what should i do to make each category in my image behave like a button..???

Comment: It will make your life a lot easier if you just cut your image to 4 pieces at make an ImageView with each piece as the source.

Comment: Yes in the end i had to do that....
The other option i thought of was to make buttons over the categories and then make them transparent but adjusting the buttons is really annoying in xml...